# php date_sunset off by one hour

Tags: php

The latitude, longitude, and UTC offset of the following should return the sunset time for Clearwater Beach, FL. Given today's date, 7/25/17, it returns 19:28, while it should return 20:28. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");

$month = $_GET["month"];
$day = $_GET["day"];
$year = $_GET["year"];

echo date_sunset(mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year), SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING, 27.9877222, -82.8281874, 90, -5);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're passing -5 as gmt offset, which is wrong, as est is -4 during summer:

> Eastern Standard Time (EST) when observing standard time (autumn/winter) are 5 hours behind Coordinated Universal Time (UTC−05:00). Eastern Daylight Time (EDT), when observing daylight saving time DST (spring/summer) is 4 hours behind Coordinated Universal Time (UTC−04:00).